# Go - How to deal with JSON response that has attribute that can be of different types

Tags: go, reddit

Let's say I have the following struct

```golang
type Response struct {
    ID string  `json:"id"`
    Edited int `json:"edited"`
}

type Responses []Response
```

Then lets say I send a request to an API, but my issue is the API docs and from testing have told me that the `edited` value can come back as a `bool` or as a `int`. This obviously upsets Go and it throws an error when decoding the response body into the struct.

```golang
// ... http GET
// response [{"edited": true, id: 1}, {"edited": 1683248234.0, id: 2}]

r := Responses{}
err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&r)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

How can I handle the above situation where I can't automatically load it into a struct? I'm assuming I'd need to do it into an interface first then filter the slice and handle the two different Response types in their own structs? But then I can't combine them!

So I'm thinking of conforming the field to one or the other, bool or int.

n.b. this relates to the Reddit API where some of the fields such as `edited`, `created`, `created_utc` don't have conforming types.

Comment: You can use `interface{}`. Or you can declare a custom type that can represent a set of different types and have it implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As told `@mkopriva`, the simplest way to handle different type of variable  is use `interface{}` type:

```
const resp = `[{"edited": true, "id": 1}, {"edited": 1683248234.0, "id": 2}, {"id": 3}]`

type Response struct {
    ID     int         `json:"id"`
    Edited interface{} `json:"edited"`
}

type Responses []Response
```

```
r := Responses{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(resp), &r)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
for _, response := range r {
    switch response.Edited.(type) {
    case float64:
        fmt.Println("float64")
    case bool:
        fmt.Println("bool")
    default:
        fmt.Println("invalid")
    }
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/4Q8fBydOlw4)</kbd>

Also you can define new `type` with custom `json.Unmarshaler` implementation:

```
type Response struct {
    ID     int    `json:"id"`
    Edited Edited `json:"edited"`
}

type Edited struct {
    BoolVal  *bool
    FloatVal *float64
}

func (e *Edited) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    boolVal, err := strconv.ParseBool(string(data))
    if err == nil {
        e.BoolVal = &boolVal
        return nil
    }
    floatVal, err := strconv.ParseFloat(string(data), 64)
    if err == nil {
        e.FloatVal = &floatVal
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New("undefined type")
}
```

```
r := Responses{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(resp), &r)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
for _, response := range r {
    edited := response.Edited
    switch {
    case edited.FloatVal != nil:
        fmt.Println("float64")
    case edited.BoolVal != nil:
        fmt.Println("bool")
    default:
        fmt.Println("invalid")
    }
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/XvIM6F0EUzJ)</kbd>